# Using environment variables in Typescript

Tags: cloudflare-workers

Is there a proper way to include environment variables in a `.ts` file? They are declared in `wrangler.toml` or through the CLI, but Typescript won't know they are there.

Currently I either use a .js file to declare these vars and then import into a `.ts`

```
//env.js
const SOMEVAR = SOMEVAR
```

Or I will need to use a `@ts-ignore` comment.

I've tried `process.env` but as expected this fails as the script isn't run in Node.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can inform TypeScript of your global variables by using the `declare global { ... }` syntax in your script:

```js
declare global {
  const SOMEVAR: string
  const ANOTHERVAR: string
}

// now you can use SOMEVAR and ANOTHERVAR as global vars
```